# How to send a POST request to a REST webservice and send JSON?

Tags: java, web-services

I have a webservice and I want to send a JSON string to it through the POST method.
Until now the webservices that I have made used the `GET` method and looked like this:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("{name}")

 public String getJson(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    //TODO return proper representation object
     CompanyDatabase cmpdb=new CompanyDatabase();
     String json=cmpdb.searchAgent(name);
    return json;
 }
```

What changes do I need to make to this method so that it accepts POST data?

Comment: It seems changing the `@GET` to `@POST` should work. Didn't it?

Comment: It gives an error in netbeans IDE

Comment: could you also post the error in your question for someone to be in a better position to help?

Comment: It shows cannot find symbol :class POST

Comment: sorry if it is too dumb, but did you import the appropriate POST annotation? It seems `@POST` is the counterpart for POST http verb from http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/snapshot/jaxrs-resources.html#d4e131.

Comment: How stupid of me..Yes i forgot to import it.So this is all i need to do?I am trying to see if it works now.The error is gone but will it accept data now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accept input data your method needs to declare what it **consumes** not produces.

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void acceptsCustomer(Customer c)  {
  // .. do something with the input.
}
```

The Customer class needs to be annotated properly to convert JSON to a Java POJO.  It's good practise to use the JAX-RS constants for the MediaTypes.

You should also consult the documentation for your JAX-RS provider (eg: RESTEasy or Jersey) as those user guides will probably have examples.